# Why is Simple Search not getting results from the Grid field in 2.7.2?

Tags: grid, simple-search

I have a site setup with a search box.  The search looks in a channel field made with Grid.  For some reason the results are not being displayed from the Grid, even though all other channels work as planned.  Is this a bug in 2.7.2?

Comment: Do you have any columns set as "searchable" within your grid field?

Comment: All columns and grid fields are set as searchable

Comment: Probably need to add some of your template code for the results.

Comment: It is just stating no results found.

Comment: Please post your search form and search results template code so we can make sure it's not an issue with your code.

Comment: {exp:search:simple_form channel="pages|leadership_team|medical_staff|employment|events|news|contacts" result_page="pages/search_results" no_result_page="pages/search_no_results" show_future_entries="yes" search_in="everywhere" status="not closed" where="all" show_expired="yes" show_future_entries="yes" results="10"}
 <span><input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="" class="search" placeholder="Keyword Search..."></span>
 <input type="hidden" name="orderby" value="title">
 <input type="hidden" name="sort_order" value="asc"> 
{/exp:search:simple_form}

Comment: {exp:search:search_results}

    <h3><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></h3>
    <p>{excerpt}</p>
    <div class="break-h"></div>

    {paginate}
     <p>Page {current_page} of {total_pages} pages {pagination_links}</p>
    {/paginate}

    {/exp:search:search_results}

Comment: No idea why it is not working.  And also, how can {auto_path} link to a row like this? http://domain.com/pages/medical-staff/12.  12 is the row ID of the grid entry.

Comment: Please move you code into the actual question. It's impossible to read here in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into a very similar instance in which I didn't specify `search_in="entries"` as a parameter so that the search runs into the entry fields rather than just the titles.

Without seeing your search form code, it is hard to say, but it sounds like this is your issue. If you are expecting to see results from content inside custom fields and aren't seeing it, try entering a search term for the title of your entry. If it yields results, change your search form to include the above parameter and try again.   ;)

Per the [docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/search/simple.html#search-in):

search_in=¶

> **search_in**="entries", **search_in**="everywhere", **search_in**="titles" This
>   parameter specifies which fields you would like to include in the
>   searching. There are three possible values:
>
> ***entries***: The search will be conducted in the entry fields and titles
>   of your channel. The associated comments will not be included.
>
> ***everywhere***: The search will be conducted in the title, entry fields,
>   and in associated comments.
>
> ***titles***: The search will be conducted in
>   the title of your entries. The channel entry fields and any associated
>   comments will not be included. If this parameter is not set, the
>   search will default to only search by “titles”.